# InCorrect output using Rfc2898DeriveBytes for password hashing

Tags: c#, .net, hash, cryptography, symmetric-key

I am certainly sure i am doing something wrong here. Using .net implementation of the algorithm i hash the password to store in database along with the salt used to hash. On validating the same password with the existing hash does not match.Here is my code

#### New Entry

```
byte[] SALT = GetRandomKey();
string password = Convert.ToBase64String((new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(txtPassword.Text, SALT)).GetBytes(20));
Session["test"] = password;
Session["salt"] = Convert.ToBase64String(SALT);
```

#### Validating

```
string HASHEDPASSWORD = Session["test"];
string SALT = Session["salt"];
string ouput = Convert.ToBase64String((new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(SALT))).GetBytes(20));
ltrResult.Text = HASHEDPASSWORD.Equals(ouput) ? "EQUAL" : "NOT EQUAL";
```

#### Get RandomKey method

```
byte[] GetRandomKey()
    {
        byte[] secretkey = new Byte[64];
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        rng.GetBytes(secretkey);
        return secretkey;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or `Convert.FromBase64String` instead of `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes`.

Comment: It's too soon to worry about performance.  Just try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

You use Convert.ToBase64String when adding items, and Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes when retrieving it...

Use Encoding.Unicode.GetString when adding a new entry and your code should work, eg:

```
private static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
{
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
}

private static byte[] GetBytes(string value)
{
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);
}
```

**Adding**

```
byte[] salt = GetRandomKey();
byte[] hash = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(txtPassword.Text, salt)).GetBytes(20);
Session["test"] = GetString(hash);
Session["salt"] = GetString(salt);
```

**Checking**

```
byte[] hash = GetBytes(Session["test"]);
byte[] salt = GetBytes(Session["salt"]);
byte[] output = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt).GetBytes(20);
ltrResult.Text = GetString(hash).Equals(GetString(output)) ? "EQUAL" : "NOT EQUAL";
```

Comment: @ricj.okelly there is no equivalent to `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` in `Convert.To...` is there

Answer (score 0):

You could store the salt as array of bytes in the session so that you don't get any differences of encoding when converting between strings and bytes:

```
byte[] SALT = GetRandomKey();
string password = Convert.ToBase64String((new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(txtPassword.Text, SALT)).GetBytes(20));
Session["test"] = password;
Session["salt"] = SALT;
```

and then to verify that a given password matches the hash you repeat the same procedure:

```
string HASHEDPASSWORD = Session["test"];
byte[] SALT = Session["salt"] as byte[];
string ouput = Convert.ToBase64String((new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SALT)).GetBytes(20));
ltrResult.Text = HASHEDPASSWORD.Equals(ouput) ? "EQUAL" : "NOT EQUAL";
```